# How to manipulate word template bookmarks field in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

I've been using microsoft interop for manipulating word documents and fill bookmarks with custom text in my windows applications. Now what i want is a similar tool to manipulate bookmark fields in .Net environment.

I tried DocX library but whenever i do

```
 doc.Bookmarks["bookmark_name"].SetText("some text");
```

its not working and field is still empty on the generated file
also i didnt find a way to manipulate checkbox fields...

Is there any other free tool which helps me to achieve what i want?

Thanks in advance

Comment: With that single line of code it is difficult to tell what the problem is. E.g. are you saving the file after manipulating it? Can you add a more complete sample?

Comment: @DirkVollmar yes am saving it but seems like its not saving my text, also didnt find a documentation on how to check a checkbox field